# Need Help resolving conflict in Jquery in wordpress site

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I have two jquery on the site. One helps the category to expand and collapse to reveal subcategory (jquery.js). Another jquery help to load the next post and display as the infinite scroll. When scrolling to next post, the URL changes to the new post's URL (jquery-2.1.4.min.js).

If we use both the function, one won't work. For, e.g., if we don't use the (jquery-2.1.4.min.js), the next post will load, but the URL won't change, and if we use the (jquery-2.1.4.min.js), the category won't be collapsable anymore.

I have attached a screenshot which will help you understand the problem.

[Screenshot of page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3xGmr.png)

The "down" icon in the category is displayed when it is working but when the function is not working it is gone. The "loading" that you can see in after the post is fetching the new post. When the category is working the URL of the next post won't be changed. If 2.1.4 is loaded, then the URL changes for the next post, but the category won't be collapsable anymore, and if I only load jquery.js, category will work, but the URL won't change anymore

I have tried using this code in functions.php but this makes matter even worse because of both of the function won't work.

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'replace_scroll' ); 
function replace_scroll(){
// Remove the Default JavaScript    


wp_dequeue_script( 'jquery' );
wp_deregister_script( 'jquery' );

// Add your own script  
wp_enqueue_script( 'script-name', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js');
```

}

I need help in fixing this issue.

Comment: Check the rendered page source and make sure your js are loading in correct order. Also, check if you are getting any js error on the page. It will help you.

Comment: Hi there, 
With this code the jquery.js is not loading at all because it is dequeue but the jquery-2.1.4 is loading.

If I dont deregister the jquery then the order is Jquer.js comes first and jquery-2.1.4.min.js comes second

Comment: When you give me access i can do resolve this issue.

Comment: The problem is it is in localhost so It is not possible to provide you the access but if you can set up the site on localhost then I can provide you with the project

Comment: what about the order of category expand js and infinite scroll js?

Comment: I managed to make it work by not having the jquery2.1.4 at att and editing the javascript that controlled the infinite js. Thank you all for contributing.